# Round to the nearest tenth position

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I'm new to this forum, but I wanted to post this question hoping to know if anyone has come across it.

Is there a formula in math to round down to the closest power of ten?

For example, 
$n$ : the number, $r$: the round value.
if $n = 101\Rightarrow r = 100$.
if $n = 322\Rightarrow r = 100$. 
if $n = 1200\Rightarrow r = 1000$. 
if $n = 77\Rightarrow r = 10$.

We need this in finance business, where trades are bought in lot sizes of $10, 100, 1000$ etc.

Comment: Yes, that's right Barry, its round down

Comment: Closest tenth or thousandth?  Well, which one? Tenths? Or thousands? 322 => 100 ??? 77 => 10?? Those aren't rounded.

Comment: @fleablood, I've edited the question to what I'm pretty sure the OP intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have to implement the answer as a script in order to use it. Here is how it can be done in python3:

```
from math import floor, log

def tenpow(x):
    return 10**(floor(log(x,10)))

tenpow(456)
```

This returns the powers of ten as desired. However, there is a problem - log(1000,10) in python returns 2.999999 not 3, which 'floors' to 2. But, if you write it 10**(floor(round(log(x,10)))) you get the wrong power of ten if the log result rounds up for other values. What is the remedy for this?

EDIT:

```
def tenpow(x):
    if x > 0:
        return 10**(len(str(x))-1)
    else:
        return 0

tenpow(345)
```

A better technique, as suggested by Barry Cipra.

Comment: As long as $n$ is an integer, you can safely add $1/2$, i.e., compute $\lfloor \log_{10}(n+{1\over2})\rfloor$.

Comment: Intriguing, will test...

Comment: Does python allow you to simply count the number of digits in an integer?  Because it's certainly easier to see that $1234567$ has $7$ digits (so it should round down to $10^{7-1}$) than it is to compute $\log_{10}(1234567)\approx6.091514664$ and then throw away most of the effort.

Comment: Yes, of course, that's the simplest way to do it.

Comment: If by "easier" we mean "takes less execution time", I am not so sure:\begin{align} &\text{>>> timeit.timeit('10**(len(str(11*13*17*19*23*29*31*37))-1)', number = 100000)}\\ &\text{0.2725730583184145}\\ &\text{>>> timeit.timeit('10**(floor(log(11*13*17*19*23*29*31*37,10)))', 'from math import floor, log', number = 100000)}\\ &\text{0.2457657722355293} \end{align}

Answer (score 2):

If you always round to the largest previous power of 10, use
$$r=10^{\lfloor\log_{10}(n)\rfloor},$$
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the order of magnitude of a given integer, $x$.

Fortunately, $m:=\lfloor \log_{10}(x)\rfloor$ gives exactly that. ($\lfloor • \rfloor$ is the floor function)

You can then consider $10^m$ for the nearest (lower) power of 10.

Comment: Thanks Riccardo. Is there a math formula to get the nearest (lower) power of 10?

Comment: @AngelaF Well, $10^m$, as I said in the answer :)

Comment: Ok, got it! Thanks Riccardo. I'll try it